# LightGBMError: invalid stod argument

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, lightgbm

I keep getting this error when I try to run this ranking model using the lightgbm package. I am trying to rank Amazon book sales by week and I am using reviews as a proxy for sales.

I used train_test split twice to split my data into a train, test and validation set.

I also tried the sklearn API I get the same error. How can I fix this?

Here is an example of the data that I use.

```
index book_nr   year    week    ratio   overall useful_review   count   thisWeek    year_week   weeks_since_start   lastWeek
0   0   2012    1   0.092749    4.842593    0.500000    108 1   201201  787 0
1   0   2012    51  0.628561    4.889706    9.713235    136 4   201251  837 0
2   0   2012    52  0.118647    4.884298    0.611570    242 1   201252  838 4
3   0   2013    1   0.199053    4.836820    0.673640    239 1   201301  839 1
4   0   2013    2   0.099310    4.755853    0.401338    299 1   201302  840 1
5   0   2013    3   0.044251    4.621212    0.897727    264 1   201303  841 1
6   0   2013    4   0.041811    4.648000    0.120000    250 1   201304  842 1
7   0   2013    5   0.115169    4.464088    1.099448    181 1   201305  843 1
8   0   2013    6   0.033397    4.463415    0.235772    123 2   201306  844 1
9   0   2013    7   0.019713    4.508065    0.072581    124 1   201307  845 2
10  0   2013    8   0.045732    4.527559    0.598425    127 3   201308  846 1
11  0   2013    9   0.061072    4.439024    0.219512    82  10  201309  847 3
12  0   2013    10  0.039745    4.647619    0.361905    105 4   201310  848 10
13  0   2013    11  0.038151    4.611765    0.188235    85  7   201311  849 4
14  0   2013    12  0.044118    4.529412    0.137255    51  17  201312  850 7
15  0   2013    13  0.032529    4.591549    0.140845    71  15  201313  851 17
16  0   2013    14  0.041667    4.589286    0.196429    56  13  201314  852 15
17  0   2013    15  0.023810    4.833333    0.119048    42  35  201315  853 13
18  0   2013    16  0.017361    4.583333    0.055556    36  35  201316  854 35
19  0   2013    17  0.034483    4.689655    0.103448    29  53  201317  855 35
20  0   2013    18  0.045798    4.500000    0.235294    34  44  201318  856 53
21  0   2013    19  0.002451    4.617647    0.029412    34  42  201319  857 44
22  0   2013    20  0.000000    4.750000    0.000000    20  95  201320  858 42
23  0   2013    21  0.000000    4.875000    0.000000    16  138 201321  859 95
24  0   2013    22  0.166667    4.521739    0.652174    23  89  201322  860 138
25  0   2013    23  0.060000    4.400000    0.160000    25  82  201323  861 89
26  0   2013    24  0.058824    4.705882    0.235294    17  161 201324  862 82
27  0   2013    25  0.038462    4.692308    0.076923    13  228 201325  863 161
28  0   2013    26  0.000000    4.769231    0.000000    13  243 201326  864 228
29  0   2013    27  0.253431    4.588235    0.852941    34  46  201327  865 243
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4728941 284315  2003    38  1.000000    4.000000    1.000000    1   588 200338  354 0
4728942 284315  2003    44  1.000000    5.000000    2.000000    1   616 200344  360 0
4728943 284316  2003    22  1.000000    5.000000    4.000000    1   699 200322  338 0
4728944 284316  2003    23  0.333333    5.000000    2.000000    1   672 200323  339 699
4728945 284316  2003    24  0.900000    4.000000    9.000000    1   692 200324  340 672
4728946 284316  2003    30  0.750000    5.000000    3.000000    1   705 200330  346 0
4728947 284316  2003    32  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   405 200332  348 0
4728948 284317  2003    15  0.500000    4.000000    1.000000    2   107 200315  331 0
4728949 284317  2003    16  0.833333    3.000000    5.000000    1   938 200316  332 107
4728950 284317  2003    21  0.500000    3.000000    1.000000    1   863 200321  337 0
4728951 284317  2003    22  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   906 200322  338 863
4728952 284318  2003    10  0.200000    4.000000    1.000000    1   849 200310  326 0
4728953 284318  2003    11  1.000000    5.000000    3.000000    1   927 200311  327 849
4728954 284318  2003    13  1.000000    5.000000    2.000000    1   782 200313  329 0
4728955 284318  2003    15  1.000000    5.000000    6.000000    1   892 200315  331 0
4728956 284318  2003    21  0.500000    4.000000    1.000000    1   830 200321  337 0
4728957 284318  2003    28  0.500000    4.000000    1.000000    1   644 200328  344 0
4728958 284318  2003    37  1.000000    4.000000    1.000000    1   816 200337  353 0
4728959 284319  2003    19  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   489 200319  335 0
4728960 284319  2003    21  1.000000    5.000000    1.500000    2   78  200321  337 0
4728961 284319  2003    25  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   601 200325  341 0
4728962 284319  2003    38  1.000000    5.000000    2.000000    1   497 200338  354 0
4728963 284320  2003    38  1.000000    5.000000    1.500000    2   105 200338  354 0
4728964 284320  2003    43  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   587 200343  359 0
4728965 284320  2003    48  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   610 200348  364 0
4728966 284320  2003    52  0.000000    5.000000    0.000000    1   235 200352  368 0
4728967 284321  2003    26  1.000000    4.000000    3.000000    1   785 200326  342 0
4728968 284321  2003    29  0.675000    4.500000    3.000000    2   121 200329  345 0
4728969 284321  2003    31  1.000000    5.000000    5.000000    1   823 200331  347 0
4728970 284321  2003    44  0.666667    4.000000    2.000000    1   774 200344  360 0
```

```
train_data = lgbm.Dataset(X_train, 
                          label=y_train, 
                          categorical_feature=[0,8],
                          group=list(X_train.groupby('year_week').count()['book_nr']))

val_data = lgbm.Dataset(X_val, 
                          label=y_val, 
                          categorical_feature=[0,8],
                          group=list(X_val.groupby('year_week').count()['book_nr']))

parameters = {
    'objective': 'lambdarank',
    'metric': 'ndcg',
    'ndcg_at': 5,
    'number_of_threads': 4,
    'max_leaves': 40,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.85,
    'bagging_freq': 5,
    'feature_fraction': 0.98,
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'verbose': 1,
    'min_data_in_leaf': 28,
    'label_gain': list(np.ones((len(X_val),1))), # I am not sure what to put here !!!
    'ignore_column': [0, 8],
    'seed': 42
}

model = lgbm.train(parameters, 
                   train_data, 
                   valid_sets=val_data, 
                   num_boost_round=1000,
                   early_stopping_rounds=50,
                   categorical_feature=['book_nr', 'year_week']
                  )
```

I keep getting the following error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LightGBMError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3f47199f6228> in <module>
      4                    num_boost_round=20,
      5                    early_stopping_rounds=20,
----> 6                    categorical_feature=['book_nr', 'year_week']
      7                   )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\engine.py in train(params, train_set, num_boost_round, valid_sets, valid_names, fobj, feval, init_model, feature_name, categorical_feature, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates, keep_training_booster, callbacks)
    195     # construct booster
    196     try:
--> 197         booster = Booster(params=params, train_set=train_set)
    198         if is_valid_contain_train:
    199             booster.set_train_data_name(train_data_name)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in __init__(self, params, train_set, model_file, silent)
   1550             self.handle = ctypes.c_void_p()
   1551             _safe_call(_LIB.LGBM_BoosterCreate(
-> 1552                 train_set.construct().handle,
   1553                 c_str(params_str),
   1554                 ctypes.byref(self.handle)))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in construct(self)
    999                                 init_score=self.init_score, predictor=self._predictor,
   1000                                 silent=self.silent, feature_name=self.feature_name,
-> 1001                                 categorical_feature=self.categorical_feature, params=self.params)
   1002             if self.free_raw_data:
   1003                 self.data = None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in _lazy_init(self, data, label, reference, weight, group, init_score, predictor, silent, feature_name, categorical_feature, params)
    789             self.__init_from_csc(data, params_str, ref_dataset)
    790         elif isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 791             self.__init_from_np2d(data, params_str, ref_dataset)
    792         elif isinstance(data, list) and len(data) > 0 and all(isinstance(x, np.ndarray) for x in data):
    793             self.__init_from_list_np2d(data, params_str, ref_dataset)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in __init_from_np2d(self, mat, params_str, ref_dataset)
    853             c_str(params_str),
    854             ref_dataset,
--> 855             ctypes.byref(self.handle)))
    856         return self
    857 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py in _safe_call(ret)
     44     """
     45     if ret != 0:
---> 46         raise LightGBMError(decode_string(_LIB.LGBM_GetLastError()))
     47 
     48 

LightGBMError: invalid stod argument
```

Comment: Are you sure you provided all the code ? It seems that the row the creates the error is not in the code you shown

Comment: Yes it gives an error at the final step where I train the model. I edited the error message a little so it is more clean now I hope.